# how to write group by query in elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Here is my Mysql query :

```
SELECT * FROM `provider` WHERE  `active` = 'Y' GROUP BY `OfferID`, `offerName`, `duration`, `price`, `downloadSpeed`, `numChannels`  LIMIT 10;
```

And now convert into Elasticsearch query, it works,

```
GET /promoapp_version_1_1/providerofferpromotionmaster/_search` "query": {
           "bool": {
        "must": [

        { "match": { "active": "Y" } }
        ]
    },  "aggs": {
"group_by_val": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "offername.keyword"
  },

  "aggs": {
    "group_by_price": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "price"
      },

      "aggs":{
          "group_by_downloadspeed":{
              "terms":{
                  "field":"downloadspeed"
              },
           "aggs":{
              "group_by_duration":{
                    "terms":{
                      "field":"duration"
                    }
                }
           }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}`
```

And how to write group by multiple fields ( offerName`,`duration`,`price`,`downloadSpeed`,`numChannels ) in ES

Answer (score 0):

What you want here to use is the ***[sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)*** metric from elasticsearch. Aggregation basically group your data into buckets of similar group.

Comment: I tried Aggregation, aggregation giving number of counts in a particular filed were after query result.

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment ?

Comment: I update my query were i tried in ES , see above query